# Ошибка сервера 401

Tags: python-3.x

пытаюсь сделать request.get получить информацию с сайта, но там ответ 401, передаю cooki те, которые используются при заходе через selenim, тоже не работает. Если перехожу с браузера который открыл selenium, все нормально открывается. (Цель, скачивать видео по ссылке)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.sdarot.website/watch/5443-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%92-%D7%94-hello-ninja/season/1/episode/2')
time.sleep(35)
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[contains(@class, "fa fa-lg fa-play")]')
btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "vjs-big-play-button")]')
btn.click()
a = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml').find(class_='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9')
a = (soup.video['src'])
cookies = (driver.get_cookies())
print(cookies)
with requests.Session() as session:
    payload = cookies
    url = f"https:{a}"
    a = session.post(f'https:{a}', data=cookies[0], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'},
                         auth=HTTPDigestAuth('me_email', '1234'))
    print(a)
    result = session.get(url)
    print(result)
```

Comment: session.auth = ('username', 'pass')

Comment: добавил, но безуспешно. Удалил свой комент так как глупость спросил

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не прошли капчу. При многократном обращении с одного IP вас могли просто забанить. Попробуйте парсером вывести всю страницу и увидите на что натыкаетесь

Comment: нет, все прекрасно работает, я выводил эту ссылку полученную супом, переходил по ней через браузер открытый selemium.ом там все открывается и работает, открываю другой браузер или его дубликат - 401